# How to parse facebook birthday field which is of "date" datatype

Tags: java, date

I was parsing the facebook field "birthday" and this should be parsed using "date" as it's datatype. I was using the following method

```
    String t = "02/22/2016";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date test = dateFormat.parse(t);
    System.out.println(test);
```

The output for above code is :

```
        Mon Feb 22 00:00:00 IST 2016 - MM/dd/yyy
```

But I want the output as only date ie., 02/22/2016

and  not in the above output format.

Comment: Just use the `format` method of `SimpleDateFormat `  : `System.out.println(dateFormat.format(test));`

Comment: ok thank you :-) It's working fine